# Find pairs of squares in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

The example above shows a 4x4 grid, with some squares "active". This is what the Javascript Array will look like for this example:

```
var activeSquares = [
    [2, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 3]
];
```

I'm looking for a function to return an array of co-ordinates of the large square's activeSquares when 4 or more activeSquares make up a larger square. This needs to work even if we have a 2x2, 2x3, 4x6 activeSquares. Also needs to work with rectangles with minimum width/height of 2. `e.g. var activeSquares = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]];`

An Example function:

```
function getLargeSquares() {
    //Code here
}

var largeSquares = getLargeSquares();
console.log(largeSquares); //[[[1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]], [another large square]]
```

The function needs to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks for your help,
Toby.

Comment: What did you achieve by yourself?

Comment: If there's a 2x3 rectangle, should the output include the 2 2x2 squares it contains? if there's a 3x3 square, should the output include the 4 2x2 squares it contains?

Comment: You have over 4k rep. This is obvious coursework - you should disclose that and you should show what you have attempted so far and when you're stuck. Not to mention that you should ask about the actual part you're stuck on and not the entire question.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin
I'm stuck on the logic itself. I felt that if I were to include what I have so far, then the problem would become far too complicated. I've organized the question like this to make it much simpler. Here is my code that I have so far, http://pastebin.com/4EKJQFvP, I hope it's all there. This is not coursework.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ^

Comment: @Joni Sorry, forgot to mention. Needs to work for rectangles too, with a minimum width/height of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework. Here is a starting point for you :)

```
function generateGrid(rows, cols, activeSquares) {
    let grid = [],
        i,
        row = [];
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        row[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
        grid[i] = row.slice();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < activeSquares.length; ++i) {
        grid[activeSquares[i][1]][activeSquares[i][0]] = 1;
    }
    return grid;
}

function findLargeSquares(grid) {
    let row, col,
        squares = [];
    for (row = 0; row < grid.length; ++row) {
        squares[row] = [];
        for (col = 0; col < grid.length; ++col) {
            squares[row][col] = getSquareSize(row, col, grid);
        }
    }
    return squares;
}

function getSquareSize(row, col, grid) {
    let i, j, d;
    d = 0;
    for (i = 0; 0 <= i && row + i < grid.length; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; 0 <= j && col + j < grid[i].length; ++j) {
            if (!grid[row + i][col + j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j <= i) break;
        ++d;
        j = 0;
    }
    return [d, d];
}

let activeSquares = [
    [2, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 3]
];

let grid = generateGrid(4, 4, activeSquares);
// [
//     [0, 0, 1, 0],
//     [1, 0, 0, 0],
//     [0, 1, 1, 1],
//     [0, 1, 1, 0]
// ]

findLargeSquares(grid);
// [
//     [[0,0], [0,0], [1,1], [0,0]],
//     [[1,1], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]],
//     [[0,0], [2,2], [1,1], [1,1]],
//     [[0,0], [1,1], [1,1], [0,0]]
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! I'll try it out. This isn't homework haha, it's for a seating planner project - https://bitbucket.org/TobyMellor/seatingplanner/commits/all - which will need to do special asset arrangement when tables are connected in squares. (http://i.imgur.com/VOBE8S0.png?1).